# Place a popup on a point that has been retrieved from a fetch query (GeoJSON response)

Tags: javascript, angular, api, openlayers

I'm programming a map with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) (4.6.5) and [Angular](https://angular.io/) (6). I use a french [API](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api) which allows to build queries like this : `https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=2.37&lat=48.357`. My goal is to replace `lon` and `lat` by the real coordinates of the client using browser geolocation. Thing I can do.

I was using, in a previous project, some functions allowing me to create a popup with informations contained in a static GeoJSON file (with no adaptable queries) and that was working but in this case it's not. I guess that the GeoJSON file is not used by the function because I receive this error :

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import Map from 'ol/map';
import WMS from 'ol/source/tilewms';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
import View from 'ol/view';
import OSM from 'ol/source/osm';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/vector';
import Geolocation from 'ol/geolocation';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/geojson';
import proj from 'ol/proj';
import Style from 'ol/style/style';
import IconStyle from 'ol/style/icon';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Overlay from 'ol/overlay';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

map: Map;
view: View;
locationSource: VectorSource;
vectorLayerLocation: VectorLayer;
loc: Style;
popup: Overlay;

  constructor() {
  }

  getLocation() {

    var geolocation = new Geolocation({
      projection: this.view.getProjection()
    });

    geolocation.setTracking(true);

    geolocation.on('change:position', () => {
      var [longitude, latitude] = proj.toLonLat(geolocation.getPosition());
      fetch(`https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=${longitude}&lat=${latitude}`).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          var features = (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(json, <any> {
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
          })
          var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
          this.locationSource.clear();
          this.locationSource.addFeatures(features);
          var pos = geolocation.getPosition();
          this.view.setCenter(pos);
          console.log(this.locationSource.getFeatures()[0].getProperties());
        });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.loc = new Style({
      image: new IconStyle(({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: 'assets/image/adresse.png'
      }))
    });

    this.view = new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      maxZoom: 19,
      zoom: 10
    });

    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
           source: new OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: this.view

    });

    this.locationSource = new VectorSource();

    this.vectorLayerLocation = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.locationSource,
      style: this.loc
    });

    this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayerLocation);

    $('#bouton_loc').on('click', function(){
      $('#bouton_loc').attr("disabled", true);
    });

    //popup

    var element = document.getElementById('popup');

    this.popup = new Overlay({
      element: element,
      autoPan: true,
      offset: [0, -30]
    });

    //Display popups

    var content_element = document.getElementById('popup-content');

    this.map.on('click', evt => {

    var feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature) {
        return feature;
      });
    if (feature) {
      var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();

      if(feature.get('label') != null) {
        var content = '<h2>' + 'Adress : ' + feature.get('label') + '</h2>';
      }

      if(feature.get('context') != null) {
        content += '<h2>' + 'Region : ' + feature.get('context') + '</h2>';
      }

      content_element = document.getElementById('popup-content');
      content_element.innerHTML = content;
      this.popup.setPosition(coord);

      var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

      closer.onclick = () => {
        this.popup.setPosition(undefined);
        closer.blur();
        return false;
      };
    }
  });

    this.map.on('pointermove', (e) => {
    if (e.dragging) {
      return;
    };
    var pixel = this.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
    var hit = this.map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);

    this.map.getViewport().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

This error means the element you are trying to set innerHTML doesn't exist.

The popup overlay is defined but never added to the map.

Comment: I have created in my `app.component.html` file these divs : `<div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
        <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
        <div id="popup-content"></div>
      </div>` Is that you want to know ?

Comment: Yes. Can you do a `console.log(content_element)` and check if it's returning the div element?

Comment: I have placed the `console.log(content_element)` line before the `content_element = document.getElementById('popup-content');` and that returns `null`

Comment: What's the output if you place it after?
`content_element = document.getElementById('popup-content');
console.log(content_element);
content_element.innerHTML = content;`

Comment: There's nothing !

Comment: I guess the `popup-content` is being called before it's defined in the html or is it being generated dynamically? Also I don't see the popup overlay being added to the map in the code.

Comment: I have created the divs with the `popup-content` one in the html file to display the popups, and I use `content_element` to associate the content of `popup-content`. I don't understand how `popup-content` could being called before it's defined in the html ? (I'm new with Javascript)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with angular js but the error seems to occur because the js couldn't find the popup element. Try adding the overlay to the map and check? or try to import and use https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-popup which is much simpler?

Comment: Owww I was mistaken I forgot the `this.map.addOverlay(this.popup);` line ! `Try adding the overlay to the map and check?` was the solution :)